# Javascript regular expression to replace newlines from textarea with wrapping <p> tags

Tags: javascript, regex

See title. I need a regular expression to replace newlines with wrapping `<p>` tags.

I tried this:

```
var pattern = new RegExp("{(?:^|(?:\x0d\x0a){2,}|\x0a{2,}¦\x0d{2,})(.+?)(?=(?:(\x0d\x0a){2,}|\x0d{2,}|\x0a{2,}|$))}");
var notesRet = notes.replace(pattern, "</p>$3<p>");
var html = notesRet;
```

But it didn't work.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
notes= notes.replace(/\r/g, '');  // normalise IE CRLF newlines
var html= '<p>'+notes.replace(/\n{2,}/g, '</p><p>')+'</p>';
```

Do you really want to take user input as HTML, though? What if they put HTML-special characters in, even `<script>alert('hello!');</script>`? If you want to treat input characters as plain text you will need HTML-escaping:

```
function encodeHTML(s) {
    return (s
        .replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
        .replace(/"/g, '&quot;').replace(/'/g, '&#39;');
    );
}

notes= encodeHTML(notes).replace(...
```

Or, perhaps more cleanly, do it with DOM:

```
var ps= notes.replace(/\r/g, '').split(/n{2,}/);
for (var i= 0; i<ps.length; i++) {
    var p= document.createElement('p');
    p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(ps[i]));
    someParentElement.appendChild(p);
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is for a content management system. Not too worried about XSS at all. Thanks for the intelligible answer though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet:

```
var html = '<p>'+notes.replace(/\r/g, '').replace(/\n([^\n]+)/g, '</p>\1<p>')+'</p>';
```

Comment: This produced this: http://ideasandpixels.com/images/hmm.jpg Each double new line creates that weird character for some reason.

Comment: @Allen Gingrich: This may be the `\r` character. Check out my improved answer.